# Regular expression to extract IPV6 address alone

Tags: python

I am trying to extract an IPV6 address from the below line. I am getting the below output.. I just want till the IPV6 address,not beyond that.That is i don't want to see Scope:Link

Code:

```
out ='ifconfig eth6.36\r\neth6.36   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr A0:36:9F:5F:24:EE  \r\n          inet addr:36.36.36.10  Bcast:36.36.36.255  Mask:255.255.255.0\r\n          inet6 addr: fe80::a236:9fff:fe5f:24ed/64  Scope:Link\r\n          inet6 addr: 2030:30:30:30::10/64  Scope:Link\r\n  UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:9000  Metric:1\r\n          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0\r\n          TX packets:62 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0\r\n          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 \r\n          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:7004 (6.8 KiB)\r\n\r\n'
pattern = '(eth6\.36\s+Link encap:Ethernet\s*HWaddr\s*\w\w:\w\w:.+\s*inet addr:36.36.36.10\s*Bcast:36.36.36.255\s*Mask:255.255.255.0\s*\inet6 addr:\s*\w\w\w\w:.+)'

match = re.search(pattern, out)
print match.groups()
```

Output:

```
('eth6.36   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr A0:36:9F:5F:24:EE  \r\n          inet addr:36.36.36.10  Bcast:36.36.36.255  Mask:255.255.255.0\r\n          inet6 addr: fe80::a236:9fff:fe5f:24ed/64  Scope:Link\r',)
```

Comment: you're capturing the entire line basically. you should capture just the ipv6 part.

Comment: The capture group is what is enclosed by the parentheses. Move the parentheses so that they enclose only what you want to capture

Comment: You mean the pattern should be  pattern = '(eth6\.36\s+Link encap:Ethernet\s*HWaddr\s*\w\w:\w\w:.+\s*inet addr:36.36.36.10\s*Bcast:36.36.36.255\s*Mask:255.255.255.0\s*\inet6 addr:\s*\w\w\w\w:)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the parentheses according to your need.
Like

```
pattern = '(eth6\.36\s+Link encap:Ethernet\s*HWaddr\s*\w\w:\w\w:.+\s*inet addr:36.36.36.10\s*Bcast:36.36.36.255\s*Mask:255.255.255.0\s*\inet6 addr:\s*\w\w\w\w:.+)  Scope:Link'
```

will get

```
In [9]: match.groups()[0]
Out[9]: 'eth6.36   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr A0:36:9F:5F:24:EE  \r\n          inet addr:36.36.36.10  Bcast:36.36.36.255  Mask:255.255.255.0\r\n          inet6 addr: fe80::a236:9fff:fe5f:24ed/64'
```

and

```
pattern = 'eth6\.36\s+Link encap:Ethernet\s*HWaddr\s*\w\w:\w\w:.+\s*inet addr:36.36.36.10\s*Bcast:36.36.36.255\s*Mask:255.255.255.0\s*\inet6 addr:\s*(\w\w\w\w:.+)  Scope:Link'
```

will get

```
In [16]: match.groups()[0]
Out[16]: 'fe80::a236:9fff:fe5f:24ed/64'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with the (standardised) output of `ifconfig`, why not dispell with *regex*s entirely, and just manipulate the string?

```
$ cat /tmp/tmp.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

out ='ifconfig eth6.36\r\neth6.36   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr A0:36:9F:5F:24:EE  \r\n          inet addr:36.36.36.10  Bcast:36.36.36.255  Mask:255.255.255.0\r\n          inet6 addr: fe80::a236:9fff:fe5f:24ed/64  Scope:Link\r\n          inet6 addr: 2030:30:30:30::10/64  Scope:Link\r\n  UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:9000  Metric:1\r\n          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0\r\n          TX packets:62 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0\r\n          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 \r\n          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:7004 (6.8 KiB)\r\n\r\n'

ip6 = out.split()[6]
print(ip6)
```

which gives you:

```
$ python /tmp/tmp.py
A0:36:9F:5F:24:EE
```